# Solving variable number system of equations using fsolve (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm solving matrix equations with fsolve for a variable number of equations/unknowns (`N`).  I've provided an example of the problem for `N=2,3`, but in the last line of each example, I have to 'hard code' each equation into fsolve.  If `N` is a variable, this will not work.  My question: **How can I call fsolve on a variable number of equations (in this case for general N)?**  The only issue is the call to fsolve.

```
clear all    
N = 2;
M(:,:,1) = rand(N);
M(:,:,2) = rand(N);
eqn = @(E,n) det(eye(N)-M(:,:,n)*diag(E));

%how do I write this line if I don't know what N is??
[E_values, Fval, Fflag] = fsolve(@(E) [eqn(E,1);eqn(E,2)],[1,1])
```

Or for `N=3` would be:

```
clear all
N = 3;
M(:,:,1) = rand(N);
M(:,:,2) = rand(N);
M(:,:,3) = rand(N);
eqn = @(E,n) det(eye(N)-M(:,:,n)*diag(E));

%how do I write this line if I don't know what N is??
[E_values, Fval, Fflag] = fsolve(@(E) [eqn(E,1);eqn(E,2);eqn(E,3)],[1,1,1])
```

(Note this may or may not have a solution depending on M, that's ok).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function, `genEqn` that outputs an array, the size of which depends on the input N.  Pass the parameter of the number of equations and the matrix M by defining a new function, `eqn`, based on the main one.  Use `eqn` as the input to fsolve.  Below is an example with 5 equations, but it works just as well for an arbitrary number.

```
function varEqFsolve

N = 5;
for k = 1:N
    M(:,:,k) = rand(N);
end

guess = ones(1,N);
eqn = @(E) genEq(E,M,N);

[E_values, Fval, Fflag] = fsolve(eqn,guess)

function F = genEq(E,M,N)

for k = 1:N
    F(k) = det(eye(N)-M(:,:,k)*diag(E));
end
```

references: http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/passing-extra-parameters.html

Answer (score 1):

Turn the anonymous function into a proper function and use a loop.

```
function main

N = round(rand*8+3);
for i=1:N
    M(:,:,i) = rand(N);
end

[E_values, Fval, Fflag] = fsolve(@(E) F(E,M),ones(N,1)) 

end

function y=F(E,M)

N = size(M,3);
y = zeros(N,1);
for i=1:N
    y(i) = det(eye(N)-M(:,:,i)*diag(E));
end

end
```